# Pod setup failure

Tags: cocoa

Right after installing cocoapods with brew and running `pod setup` it exists with the following messages:

```
Setting up CocoaPods master repo
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/yaml.rb:5:in `<top (required)>':
It seems your ruby installation is missing psych (for YAML output).
To eliminate this warning, please install libyaml and reinstall your ruby.
Assertion failed: (0 && "LoadedImage not found"), function findLoadedImage, file /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libdyld/dyld-655.1/dyld3/ClosureBuilder.cpp, line 469.
Abort trap: 6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely an issue with your ruby config. I use RVM to manage my ruby installations and running `rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles` fixed the issue.

Comment: I had to remove RVM altogether and limit myself to the default OS ruby, i will give this a try however.